# await function not executed?

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I found this piece of code online on csharpstar.com as I was trying to understand more about `async` and `await`. Can someone help me understand why when I debug it I reach the line where `await client.GetStringAsync ("http://www.CsharpStar.com");` is assigned to result, and then the debugger doesn't move onto the next line from try, and doesn't enter catch either, it just seems to resume execution from Main?
If the await line throws a timeout error or something should it not go to catch?

Also weird that when control/flow resumes to Main, it doesn't go through line ReadLine(), which it executed earlier (before entering the GetSite method), however the ReadLine() takes effect after exiting the GetSite method.

What is the explanation of await function disrupting the regular flow? Why can't I debug the next line, so I can see the value stored into the result variable?

```
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using static System.Console;

namespace CSharpStar
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() => GetSite()); 
            ReadLine(); // **...to here (2)**
        }

        private async static Task GetSite()
        {
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            try
            {
               var result = await client.GetStringAsync ("http://www.CsharpStar.com"); // **debugger jumps from here (1)**
               WriteLine(result);
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                try
                {
                    //This asynchronous request will be invoked if the first request is failed. 
                    var result = await client.GetStringAsync ("http://www.easywcf.com");
                    WriteLine(result);
                }
                catch
                {
                    WriteLine("Entered Catch Block");
                }
                finally
                {
                    WriteLine("Entered Finally Block");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what article you were reading, but you should stop there. `Task.Factory.StartNew` is not recommended, but `Task.Run` is.
What is happening is that the control is returned to the caller (`Main` in this case) as soon as the `await` keyword is reached. Since you are not `await`ing for the `Task` to finish, the program goes on to the `Console.WriteLine` line. This is known as a *fire and forget* call.

If you want to wait for the function to finish, change your code to:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // change to the recommended Task.Run method
    var task = Task.Run(() => GetSite()); 
    task.GetAwaiter().GetResult(); // block until the Task is finished
    ReadLine(); 
}
```

Comment: @the.Doc That depends on how you want the task to be run.

Comment: But in your example, the task you are awaiting is not the task returned by GetSite so this doesn't solve the ops problem.

Comment: @the.Doc Are you sure about that? Why don't you try it out and comment later?

Comment: apologies, big difference between Task.Run(()=>GetSite()); and Task.Run(()=>{ GetSite(); }); Func vs Action

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto What would be the use-case in a console application to wrap an IO-bound asynchronous call in a CPU-bound asynchronous call?

Comment: @ckuri There's none, I was demonstrating the correct use of initiating tasks. For this case, `var task = GetSite();` would of course be ok